# All three indicators of a Spike guard/ Spike buster shining leading to shock like sensations

Tags: electrical, spike

A standard Spike buster/ Spike guard has 3 LEDs in a horizontal line to indicate if the connections are OK, open or reversed depending upon which one or two of the LEDs are shining. This information is usually printed just below the row of LEDs. It however does not mention what it means when all three indicators are shining.

In our house, we use this spike guard to attach a mobile charger,  monitor of a desktop, modem and laptop charger. Usually the first and the third indicators lit up  implying "all OK" . However, intermittently, all of a sudden, the middle indicator also lists up a for variable period of time. During this interval when all three LEDs are shining, we get shock like sensation on touching metallic knob of geyser in bathroom (which is not connected to the spike guard), keypad of the laptop and cabinet of the desktop. As and when the third ( middle) LED stops shining, this current like sensation also disappears. We have changed the spike guard multiple times, sought help of electricians, checked and changed earthing and have performed Google search but in vain.

Nobody in the family is related to to electrical engineering. Could you please find out the fault and let us know what we should do to avoid this current like sensation. Thank you.

Attached herewith is an image whilst the middle LED was flickering along with stable first and third LED . [image]

Comment: Sounds like you have lost the earth/ground connection.

Comment: Thank you.... But we have got earthing checked by multiple electricians and all have claimed it to be okay on testing...

Comment: Try a replacement.

Comment: Thank you. But as mentioned in the question, we have already replaced the spike guard thrice!

Comment: Well, I stand by my original comment then.